# Cement board around shower base-should it sit on the flange or floating above it (1/4" of less above it)?

Tags: shower

Most of the questions I am seeing are asking about the cement board sitting behind the flange. In my opinion that is inviting for trouble.

The other two major options are:
-sit on the flange like below and here are two sub options

```
   a) sitting on the flange making contact
```

[image]

```
   b) sitting above the flange no contact
```

[image]

-sitting in front of the flange like below (this is from the manual of my shower base , see the link below)

[image]

For completeness here are the specs (sizes) of my shower base, [the manual](https://www.kohler.ca/webassets/kpna/catalog/pdf/en/1185992_2.pdf) says install the shower base in front of the flange but I am of the opinion (and my current situation is forcing me to do that) that it is better to install above the flange, sitting on it.
[image]